# ValidatorEnable not disabling requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side

I have some client side script in an ASPX file that enables or disables a required field validator based on whether the form field is visible or not.

```
var oVal1 = document.getElementById(v1);
var oVal2 = document.getElementById(v2);
ValidatorEnable(oVal1, true);
ValidatorEnable(oVal2, false);
```

When I alert the enabled properties of oVal1 and oVal2, they show the correct settings for this condition - oVal1 is enabled, oVal2 is disabled.

The problem is the validators are ALWAYS firing. I need to selectively disable one since the field isn't visible, it's not required in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by field visible?
if it is `<asp:TextBox ID="v1" ... Visible="false"...` then it isn't rendered and not available as `document.getElementById('v1')`. In this case set `Visible="false"` to its validator as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
  var ControlandValidator = {    
            "ControlNameGoeshere" : "0"//Validate 1, Not to Validate : 0   
    };

    $(document).ready(function () { // Or trigger where u want   
        $.each(ControlandValidator, function (index, validate) {   
            var validatorName = document.getElementById(index);  
            if (validatorName != null) {  
                ValidatorEnable(validatorName, parseInt(validate) == 1 ? true : false);  
            }  
        });
```